# What device/system would be used to increase rpm and decrease torque of some shaft?

Tags: gears, generator

As posed above...

(sorry if not asked correctly - my first time on SE)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Gearbox, sprockets and chains, or pulleys and belts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pair of gears.

The ratio of diameters will control the speed relationship as well as the torque.

Or a pair of pulleys but then they may be some slip  between driven and driver, however the ratio of diameters still applies.

Or, if the locations of the two shafts are separate then a hydraulic motor and pump could be used.